# Adding discord.ui.Select to a modal Discord py

Tags: discord.py

I've made a ticket bot , for the ticket reason I'm using a Modal

```py
class TicketInputReason(discord.ui.Modal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(title="Ticket", timeout=90)

        self.resp = None
        options = [
            discord.SelectOption(label="Become an admin", emoji=""),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label="A script problem", value="script", emoji=""),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label="Other ...", value="Other", emoji="")
        ]
        self.add_item(discord.ui.Select(
            placeholder="Catégorie du ticket", options=options, custom_id="category_select", min_values=1, max_values=1,))
        self.add_item(discord.ui.TextInput(label="Raison", placeholder="Raison du ticket",
                      custom_id="reason_input", max_length=50, min_length=10))

    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        self.stop()
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title=f"Ticket created!", color=discord.Color.blurple())
        embed.add_field(name="**Salon**",
                        value=f"{ticket_channel_mention}", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="**Category**",
                        value=f"{self.children[1].value}", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="**Raison**",
                        value=f"{self.children[0].value}", inline=True)
        embed.set_thumbnail(
            url=icon_url)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
```

But when I create a ticket I have the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 425, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "\\serveur\gondin\BotDiscord\skybot.py", line 1179, in ticket
    await interaction.response.send_modal(modal)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\interactions.py", line 914, in send_modal
    await adapter.create_interaction_response(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\webhook\async_.py", line 220, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In data.components.0.components.0: Value of field "type" must be one of (4,).
```

I tried to disable the Select ui and everything was working perfectly and I don't know if it is really possible so if not , are there any good alternatives because I'm using a view and not a slash command so I can't just use a Literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have any other UI in a modal other than text inputs because Discord doesn't support them, for now at least. So the best thing you can do is get the selection beforehand, like from the slash command or prefix command options. Like:

```py
class AModal(discord.ui.Modal):
    def __init__(self, animal: str):
        super().__init__(...)
        self._selected_animal = animal

        ...

    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message(
            content=f"Your animal is {self._selected_animal}"
        )

@bot.tree.command()
async def some_command(
    interaction: discord.Interaction,
    animal: typing.Literal["Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit"]
):

    ...

    await interaction.response.send_modal(AModal(animal))
```

Comment: Any news on that? A Modal is pretty useless for most stuff if you're limited to text input only. :(